# Group records and display non null values for columns

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
id | name | phone  | address
 1 | bob  | 123457 | NULL
 2 | bob  | NULL   | some address
```

I need the output to be as follows:

```
id | name | phone  | address
 1 | bob  | 123457 | some address
```

How can I accomplish this in SQL?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: What if you have three or four rows for bob? And what if each row has a different phone or address?

Comment: and what if the phone different number shows up?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? On SO it is frowned upon to not try first and show your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

By observation, the following query should work:

```
SELECT
    MIN(id) AS id,
    name,
    MAX(phone) AS phone,
    MAX(address) AS address
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name;
```

This makes several assumptions:

- There is only one non `NULL` value in the `phone` and `address` column
- You want to select minimum `id` value for each name group of records

In the absence of further information, these seems like reasonable assumptions.

Comment: Maybe you should first ask the OP to clarify his problem before jumping to an answer based on assumptions...